# Transversality of sections

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

I am working through a paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.1690.pdf on $J$-holomorphic surves and I don't understand the part in the theorem

[image]

where it says "smooth section transverse to the zero section".

I could interpret this as $s(t) \neq 0_{section}(t)=0$ but this doesn't make sense to me..

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Do you know what transverse means?

Comment: At least I think so :D.. I know what it means for two submanifolds to be transverse and for a smooth map and a submanifold

Comment: Maybe I understood zero section wrong? I thought its the section which maps $x \mapsto 0 \in T_xM$.

Comment: You need to look up what it means for two maps to be transverse. In this case the maps are $s$ and the zero section.

Answer (score 2):

First I will assume that $k\leq n$ so the statement makes more sense.

Let $z$ denote the zero section of $\pi \colon E\to B$. We have that $s$ and $z$ are transverse at $y\in s(B)\cap z(B)$ if for  $x = \pi(y)$
$$Ds_x(T_xB) + Dz_x(T_xB) = T_yE.$$

We say that the sections are transverse if they are transverse at every point of intersection of their images (which can be empty).

Take a point $p\in B$ and a small neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $B$ such that $E|_V \simeq V \times \mathbb{R}^k$ is trivial. Then in this trivialization we have 
$$
z\colon V \rightarrow V \times \mathbb{R}^k, \quad z(x) = (x,0) \\
s\colon V \rightarrow V \times \mathbb{R}^k, \quad s(x) = (x,f(x)) \\
$$
for some (smooth) function $f\colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$. Now $s(p)= z(p)$  if and only if $f(p) =0$ and the transversality condition translates to $Df_p$ having maximal rank ($=k$).

Note that $s^{-1}(0) = s^{-1}\left(s(B)\cap z(B) \right)$ is (locally) given by the system of equations $f(x)=0$ and the transversality condition allows us to apply the Implicit function theorem to prove that $s^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold of dimension $n-k$.

Answer (score 0):

The above claim is not different from the usual transversality theorem which says that if $f: N \to M$ is transversal to $Z$, $f \pitchfork Z, Z$ being a submanifold, then $f^{-1}(Z)$ is a submanifold. The zero section as a set is a submanifold, which happens to be diffeomorphic to $B$, and the section $s$ being transversal to $0$-section is same as $s$ being transversal to the submanifold $0$-section. Hence the conclusion.